# Parse Date, CET vs CEST, invalid TimeZone, unparseable

Tags: java, sqlite, date, codenameone

I am using shannah´s Data Access Library to access my objects via his DAO interfaces.

I face a very strange behaviour with parsing the date values when the unmap method gets called once my stuff is in the database. It only fails on CEST (Central European Summer Time)

I tried to use the NumberUtil.dateValue Method to parse it but it still fails...

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse string date format Thu Mar 31 00:00:00 CEST 2016.  Could not find appropriate format parser.
```

i defined DateFormat´s as these

```
        dateFormats[0] = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        dateFormats[1] = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        dateFormats[2] = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy");
        dateFormats[3] = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
```

also tried to trim the String but it didnt help.

Im out of ideas as SDF doesnt have the constructor as the normal JDK with the 2nd parameter beeing the Locale.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Method that take date time string , input pattern and out put pattern,that return formatted date as string

public String parseDate(String dateTime,String inputPattern, String outputPattern) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

    Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateTime);
    String str = outputFormat.format(date);

    return str;
}
// call method
String date = parseDate("Thu Mar 31 00:00:00 CEST 2016" ,"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy:HH:mm:ss");

// print date
System.out.println(date);

// Result 
03-31-2016:03:00:00
```

Comment: This results for me in an Exception:

         com.codename1.l10n.ParseException: Invalid timezone value

AND

        com.codename1.l10n.ParseException: Not implemented

Comment: I have updated method , Added time zone "Locale.ENGLISH"

Comment: unfortunately there is no DateTime class, my approach was to use this Method: Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone() but SimpleDateFormat class is lacking a setTimeZone method.

Again there is a class from shannah called SimpleDateFormatExt but it didnt help me either in this case.

EDIT: Khalid, that wont work because CodenameOne doesnt have that constructor implemented

Comment: Try this approach |   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.EN_US);
cal.setTime(sdf.parse("Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011"));// all done

Comment: You do mean the Locale.ENGLISH? as stated before, it will not work because the SimpleDateFormat class does not have that stuff implemented.(Constructor doesnt exists). As far as i see the CN1 FW is mostly based on JDK1.3 iirc

Comment: We don't support the java.util.Locale class which is pretty complex as it leads to a lot of underlying system complexities. Most parsing/date formatting is done thru the much simplified L10NManager which might not suite your needs as it's not as elaborate as the `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: I already had a look yesterday on the L10Manager class, its fine for formating a date object but the problem i have is to make a Date out of that String, and it fails as long as i have that CEST stuff in the String. That String also fails on the RestService side even with CET so i dont have a clue what is happening there.

Answer (score 0):

I now did a workaround to this issue, i can still develop my api and stuff further but to be honest i dont like this fix, as i think it will make some problems with the TimeZones later.

Can someone with more experience tell me anything about this fix, if it may cause errors with TimesZones and Summer/Winter times?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
String dateValue = plannedDate;
String year = dateValue.substring(dateValue.length() - 4);
dateValue = dateValue.substring(0, 20);
dateValue += year;
this.plannedDate = sdf.parse(dateValue);
```

Any advice or possible fixes are welcome (y)